# Where could the water be coming from found in this hole my dogs dug?

Tags: water, hole, sinkhole, underground

My puppies have been digging in our yard mainly one specific area for awhile. The other day I noticed my puppy's feet were wet. I went to the hole and found water had filled in. It is only about a 1 foot deep. I also discovered some pavers have been put in the ground in that area. We live by a lake which is at least 200 ft away and the hole is at least 20 ft above the lake. I am wondering where the water is coming from, it does soak in and go away as long as the dogs don't dig anymore but I am concerned. I almost want to dig to find out where the water is coming from but don't want it to give away and get hurt.I live in Florida. We put in a fence on the other side of the property just last spring and never found any water and dug the post holes around 2.5 ft deep and are closer to the lake than the newly found hole.

Comment: It's strange water collects only when disturbed. That probably eliminates a leaking water line as an explanation. My guess is it's a natural seep, a spring without enough flow for water to be collectible.

Comment: Could be water that is draining down to the lake from ground above the hole, especially if it rained recently.

Comment: It has been pretty dry here recently. I'm wondering if there was some type of problem before and that's why someone put some pavers in the ground and covered them.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is this is just normal groundwater, either a natural spring or a high water table at that spot. (Other possibilities would be a leak, rainwater, or proximity to a septic system field.)

The water table height may be higher or lower depending on the season and amount of rain / snow. The water table may well be higher than the lake surface... they do not need to be the same height. The water table may be very irregular, depending on the underground position of rock, different types of soil, sources of water, etc, so just because there was no water somewhere else on your property doesn't preclude the possibility.

(The presence of water for only a brief time after digging is interesting, and I can't easily explain it. It's possible that by disturbing the soil your dogs were compacting it a bit, forcing water out, much like squeezing a wet sponge. This can be a problem in large-scale soil compaction projects, like preparing a lot for a new foundation. I would be surprised if dogs could have the same effect, but maybe if you have soft soil with a high water content it's possible.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. We do have soft soil living in Florida. I think we will just fill it in and hope for the best.